# How can I make a checkbox list in a telegram bot?(Python)

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm currently using python-telegram-bot for create telegram bot. And I want to get multiple choise in keybord in my bot, example - http://prntscr.com/1026ib2. How I can do this?
I'm trying understand any code on PHP, but unfortunately couldn't implement it in python.
Thanks for smth information.

Answer (score 0):

Use [editMessageReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) method when you recieve incoming Update with inline_query (Update with inline query is sent when user presses inline button). Checkboxes are made using emoji in text of inline button.

Answer (score 0):

You can check a source code of ToBeDo checklist bot:

```
CHECK_CHAR = '✅'
UNCHECK_CHAR = '⬜'

lines = msg.split('\n')
keyboard = []

index = 0
for line in lines:
    line_strip = line.strip()
    if line_strip == '':
        continue

    keyboard.append([InlineKeyboardButton(
        f"{CHECK_CHAR if previous_state.get(line_strip, False) else UNCHECK_CHAR} {line_strip}", 
        callback_data=f"toggle__{index}"
    )])
    index += 1

reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

...
update_object.reply_text('Click to toggle', reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Code taken from here https://github.com/devforth/tobedo/blob/master/handler.py#L177

Bot link to try how it looks and works: https://t.me/tobedo_bot